# ORACLE SQL : SUM in first row with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to obtain the following results in a query

Here is my table

| Line_num | Line_typ | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| 2000 | 7 | 5000 |
| 3000 | 7 | 3000 |
| 4000 | 7 | 2000 |
| 5000 | 6 | 0 |
| 6000 | 9 | 3000 |
| 7000 | 7 | 2000 |
| 8000 | 1 | 2000 |

What I want as result is this

| Line_num | Line_typ | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 6 | 10000 (0+5000+3000+2000) |
| 5000 | 6 | 5000 (0+3000+2000) |
| 8000 | 1 | 2000 |

Basically to display only rows with line_typ in (6,1) but sum the column costs of all other lines in between.

Thank you for your ideas and help !!

Ivan

Comment: Can you better describe the logic which determines how the groups of records are to be formed here?

Comment: Hello Tim, yes i'm taking only the line_typ = 6 or 1, and group using the line_num, so the first group will be line_num (1000,2000,3000,4000....) until I have a next row with line_typ 6 or 1, then it should be a new group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Tim Biegeleisen's answer is excellent, but needs some intermediate products and oracle features, can be seen when one uses minimal SQL:

- Select line_typ in (1, 6), order by line_num.
- Sum the cost for second run over the table with larger line_num *n*, but
- where (third run) there is no line_typ in (1, 6) before *n*.

Basic complexity O(N³), with indices a bit less.

So:

```
select h.line_num, h.line_typ,
 (select sum(cost)
  from tbl g
  where g.line_num >= h.line_num
  and not exists (select *
                  from tbl
                  where line_num > h.line_num
                  and line_typ in (1, 6)
                  and line_num <= g.line_num)
 ) as cost
from tbl h
where h.line_typ in (1, 6)
order by h.line_num
```

*(Given for non-oracle searchers.)*

Here is a link to a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7880232a62876fc9cafe4796e0b010ea).

Comment: My mind doesn't work this way, but +1 for a more efficient answer.

Comment: Thank you Joop & Tim, this is the first time I have asked a question and I am amazed by the speed and quality of your answers! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a play on a gaps and islands problem.  Each island begins upon encountering a `Line_typ` value of 1 or 6, and ends right before a record containing another 1 or 6 value.  We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function to find the groups, then report the sums of cost.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN Line_typ IN (1, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY Line_num) AS grp
    FROM cte t
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(Line_num) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS Min_Line_num
    FROM cte2 t
)

SELECT MIN(Line_num) AS Line_num,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Line_num = Min_Line_num THEN Line_typ END) AS Line_typ,
       SUM(Cost) AS Cost
FROM cte3 t
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(t.Line_num);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY line_num
  MEASURES
    FIRST(line_num) AS line_num,
    FIRST(line_typ) AS line_typ,
    SUM(cost)      AS total_cost
  PATTERN (match_type other_type*)
  DEFINE
    match_type AS line_typ IN (6, 1),
    other_type AS line_typ NOT IN (6, 1)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (line_num, line_typ, cost) AS
  SELECT 1000, 6,    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2000, 7, 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3000, 7, 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4000, 7, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5000, 6,    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6000, 9, 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7000, 7, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8000, 1, 2000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | LINE_NUM | LINE_TYP | TOTAL_COST |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1000 | 6 | 10000 |
> | 5000 | 6 | 5000 |
> | 8000 | 1 | 2000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eb59164bffccf1a9f5c69fcfd9550b12)*